# MongoDB text search: find both words in one document

Tags: mongodb

I have the fol docs:

```
db.docs.insert({_id:1, title:"make: aaa, model: 12"})
db.docs.insert({_id:2, title:"make: bab, model: 1"})
db.docs.insert({_id:3, title:"make: bab, model: 12"})
```

I search for `bab 12` and need mongo to return me only doc #3.
Unforturnately I cannot find a suitable query.
Obviously  `db.docs.find( { $text: { $search: "bab 12" } } )` returns all 3 docs
and `db.docs.find( { $text: { $search: "\"bab 12\"" } } )` returns nothing.

Is there a way to do this, without regex (which is too slow - I have millions of docs in docs collection)?

Comment: That's exactly what the linked dupe is asking as well. Note that each word is separately quoted.

Comment: Wowa, really! I tried it with quoting both words separately and it worked! Thank you, sir, you've opened my eyes)